# viewWillAppear is not being called when using Modal Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a **Table View Controller** and a **Modal segue** to which I can add to the data which is populating the `UITableView`. My code went from working to not working because the `viewWillAppear` is now not being called when closing the modal view, therefore the table view is not repopulating the table with new data.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    println("View Will Load was called")
}
```

I even added the following code when closing the modal view.

```
 self.presentingViewController!.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Does anybody know why this may be happening. Like I already mentioned it was working fine and can not figure out why it has stopped working now.

Comment: `viewwillLoad`? or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @Leo sorry typo, made edits.

Comment: aside of the original question - you should call `super.viewWillAppear(animated:)`

Comment: @MaxK still no luck :( made edits including your reply

Comment: But first time, after viewDidLoad, it was called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** It seems I changed Modal segue to **Over Current Context** from **Over Context**  therefore because the view doesn't go away it doesn't recall `viewWillLoad`. I changed it back and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

When using a navController to push, assuming VC1 is pushing VC2 and you are using a custom presentation style to push your VC2, depending on which style you choose viewWillAppear of VC1 will not be called when VC2 is popped. Here is a list of when is called according to its presentation style.

UIModalPresentationStyle, iPhone, iPad

.fullScreen YES YES
.pageSheet YES NO
.formSheet YES NO
.currentContext YES YES
.custom NO NO
.overFullScreen NO NO
.overCurrentContext NO NO
.blurOverFullScreen  only on tvOS - N/A, N/A
.popover YES NO
.none CRASH CRASH